# Calculate the curvilinear integral $\int \limits_{(-1,2)}^{(1,-2)} (3x^2-2xy+y^2)dx + (2xy-x^2-3y^2)dy$

Tags: integration

$$I = \int \limits_{(-1,2)}^{(1,-2)} (3x^2-2xy+y^2)dx + (2xy-x^2-3y^2)dy$$

I tried to use fact that $\int \limits_{Г_{AB}} Pdx + Qdy =  u(B) -u(A)$

Am I right that $u(x,y)  = \int \limits_{-1}^{x} (3x^2-2xy+y^2)dx + \int \limits_{2}^{y} (-2y-1-3y^2)dy + C$

I got  $u(x,y) = 1 + x^3 + y - x^2 y + y^2 + x y^2 + 14 - y - y^2 - y^3 + C$

So $I = u(1,-2) - u(-1, 2) = 30$
Is this method correct in this case?

Comment: Please note that math commands that unnecessarily force taller expressions, such as `\limits` here, should not be used in titles. They result in improperly aligned text and wasteful white spaces on the front page, making it more annoying to scroll through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the given line is $y = -2x$ for $x$ from $-1$ to $1$.

Then substitute, noting $\mathrm{d}y = -2 \mathrm{d}x$
$$I = \int_{-1}^1 3x^2 + 4x^2 + 4x^2 + \left[ -4x^2 - x^2 - 12x^2 \right] \cdot -2 \; \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^1 45x^2 \mathrm{d}x = \left[15x^3\right]_{-1}^1 = 30$$